# How to use Http.Context.current() in a Promise in Play?

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.2

In Play Framework 2.2.2, I'd like to return a Promise. However I'm calling a function which needs access to the variables stored in `Http.Context.current()` (the current logged in user, the JPA connection...).

Of course, since the Promise is executed in another thread, it doesn't have access to `Http.Context.current()`. Can I preserve it in the Promise, or should I restore it manually? Is there another pattern I should use?

Example:

```
public static Promise<Result> getAvailableServices() {
    return new Promise.promise(new Function0<Result>(){
        @Override
        public Result apply() throws Throwable {
            // Long operation
            List<Services> data = buildResult();
            // Render the template
            // (The header of the template requires access to 
            // Http.Context.current().args.get("usermodel"))
            return Results.ok(services_template.render(services));
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: This question may be considered as a rewording of  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17886630/play-2-1-1-java-can-i-access-http-context-current-from-an-arbitrary-asynchro

Comment: We can pass another argument to Promise.promise(), the ExecutionContext. Is [HttpExecutionContext](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.1/api/scala/index.html#play.core.j.HttpExecutionContext) part of the answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, `HttpExecutionContext` is what you need.

When an `HttpExecutionContext` is created it [gets the current thread's `Http.Context` and stores it](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/2.2.2/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/core/j/HttpExecutionContext.scala#L11-L12). Then, when the `HttpExecutionContext` is later used to execute code [it restores the `Http.Context`](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/2.2.2/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/core/j/HttpExecutionContext.scala#L29-L43).

[All `Promise` methods use an `HttpExecutionContext`](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/2.2.2/framework/src/play/src/main/java/play/libs/F.java#L286-L288) [wrapped around the default ExecutionContext](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/2.2.2/framework/src/play/src/main/java/play/libs/HttpExecution.java#L30-L32) so they should propagate the `Http.Context` correctly across threads.

Your example code above should work fine, for example. However you do need to make sure that when you *call* `getAvailableServices`, that the `Http.Context` is available in the thread you're calling from. If the `Http.Context` isn't available when you call the method, then the `HttpExecutionContext` will be unable to capture the `Http.Context` from that thread and propagate it when the promise's `Function0` is applied.

Comment: It works! I used ```Promise.promise(..., HttpExecution.defaultContext())```. Thank you very much!