# PlayDependencyClassLoader does not find application code

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

When a third party dependency attempts to load a class defined in a Play application using

```
Class.forName(className, true, Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader());
```

Play will throw a `ClassNotFoundException` because the context class loader is of type `PlayDependencyClassLoader` which apparently only contains classes defined in jar dependencies.

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: eventstore.Commit
    at org.mapdb.SerializerPojo.classForName(SerializerPojo.java:96)
    at org.mapdb.SerializerPojo$1.deserialize(SerializerPojo.java:74)
    at org.mapdb.SerializerPojo$1.deserialize(SerializerPojo.java:39)
```

This only occurs when Play is started with `play run`.  Starting Play with `play start` loads the class correctly.

It would be a shame to sacrifice the class hot-swapping because of this behavior.  Is there a known workaround?

Comment: There was a similar thread here, but no apparent resolution at that time:  https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/play-framework/rh6HVYw5zz0

Comment: Looks like the idea for a workaround might be here: http://ben-tech.blogspot.be/2013/05/play-run-in-dev-mode-and.html and http://answer.techwikihow.com/51475/upgrade-playframework-2-1-1-creates-json-deserialization-problems-jeckson-connected-akka-actor.html

Comment: The hack is to add `Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(Play.application.classloader)` before any call that fails in this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A hacky type fix for now is to wrap invocations of third party libraries that use `Class.forName` with a function like this:

```
  // see Play classloader bug https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/822
  def fixClassLoader[E](f: () => E) = {
    val old = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()
    try {
      Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(Play.application.classloader)
      f()
    } finally {
      Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(old)
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Play's `HttpExecutionContext` can also be used to propagate the `ClassLoader` across threads. The `HttpExecutionContext` also propagates the `Http.Context` thread local, if one is set.

See my answer here: [How to use Http.Context.current() in a Promise in Play?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23198375/how-to-use-http-context-current-in-a-promise-in-play/23204616#23204616)

See also [Play issue #2847 – *classloader issues when using "run"*](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/2847).

Comment: Rich - I saw your effort on this during my research yesterday and it was helpful to get there in the end.  In this case, the offending code is being called on startup in a `GlobalSettings` implementation, so I don't understand how `HttpExecutionContext` comes into play.  Perhaps this only works in the context of code executed in Actions?

Comment: In `GlobalSettings` you might be best to use `Play.application.classLoader` directly. But if you want to start asynchronous code from `GlobalSettings` then using an `ExecutionContext` that propagates the `ClassLoader` might be helpful.

Here is a relevant Play issue: https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/2847