# Play Framework HTTPS SSLEngineProvider override

Tags: playframework

I have followed the example as per:

https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ConfiguringHttps

However, when I connect to the server the following exception is thrown.

```
[error] - play.core.server.NettyServer$PlayPipelineFactory - cannot load SSL context
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: mypackage.CustomSSLEngineProvider
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381) ~[na:1.8.0_51]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_51]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_51]
    at play.core.server.ssl.ServerSSLEngine$.createSSLEngineProvider(ServerSSLEngine.scala:27) ~[play-server_2.11-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
```

My command:

```
./activator run -Dhttp.port=disabled -Dhttps.port=9443 -Dplay.server.https.engineProvider=mypackage.CustomSSLEngineProvider -Dhttps.keyStore=conf/keystore.jks -Dhttps.keyStorePassword=changeit -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=conf/truststore.jks -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=changeit -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048 -Djdk.tls.rejectClientInitiatedRenegotiation=true
```

I've done a full build and the class is in the package. I can only assume that the classloader cannot see the class, possibly due to its scope?

Can anyone shed any light on this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a fix/work around. Turns out if you are running the application with 'run' your java class cannot be found under the classloader.

[PlayDependencyClassLoader does not find application code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23878824/playdependencyclassloader-does-not-find-application-code)

So the workaround was to create a separate JAR which contained the CustomSSLProvider. Now it works.