# Propagate Http.Context.current() to hibernate models in Play Framework

Tags: playframework, sharding

I'm in the process of implementing sharding for a web app. I begin by intercepting the request in the Global object and check for the primary key id in the GET query parameters, the POST data and the URI path.

```
@Override
    public Action onRequest(Http.Request request, Method actionMethod) {
        return new Action.Simple() {
            @Override
            public F.Promise<Result> call(Http.Context ctx) throws Throwable {
                ShardingService.checkAndSetShardInfo(ctx);

                return delegate.call(ctx);
            }
        };
    }
```

Using this primary key, I get the shard of the models involved in the request, and map the Model class with the shard and keep this mapping in Http.Context.current().

My database calls are made in a separate execution context:

```
Promise.promise(() -> executeBgTask(tsec), Akka.system().dispatchers().lookup("db-dispatcher")).map((Integer i) -> ok("Got exec req for " + i + " secs"));
```

I had a couple of questions:

1. How do I access Http.Context.current() in the db-dispatcher execution context so that the shard mapping is available in the db call execution context?
2. I think that it may not be the cleanest way to pass around sharding info through the call stack in the session object. Is there a cleaner way available in Play!?

Some googling led me to this:

[How to use Http.Context.current() in a Promise in Play?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23198375/how-to-use-http-context-current-in-a-promise-in-play)

However, in the suggested answer, we're still executing in the default context.